# How to flip card by a corner?

Tags: cocos2d

After searching "flip card" in google and our stackexchange site, there is no result and I have no ideas about **how to flip a card by a corner**.
I am developing a ios card game with cocos2d, in this game, i just want to touch the right-bottom corner of back face, and hold on moving towards left-up direction. With moving a little distance, the card can flip to front face.
Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but in http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php they do exactly what you are asking for (mid-right example) using CSS3. Perhaps looking at the source code you can get some inspiration!

Comment: You could just provide animations for the card flip - I can't think of an easy way of doing that programmatically. You could look at the link that Dan gave or at the flipping mechanism provided in Cocoa (Apple-specific).

Comment: The examples on the link site that Dan gave is not the effect i want.But still thanks.@Polar maybe i'll go deep into the flipping mechanism in Cocoa.

Comment: Have a look at this example for inspiration: http://www.mypageflip.com/demos/xml-basic/default.html

note the bending effect is faked; it's a gradient on a standard flat image of the flipped side.

Comment: @CongXu Yes, it's the very effect that i want!

Answer (score 3):

Your image example doesn't fit reality for the card you have shown. You are showing the wrong corner, but that's just me pointing out little things ;)

I will give you the simplified version for being able to flip an area that's a triangle.

1. Calculate the x and y offset from the bottom right corner. (it's the difference between the world coords of the dragged corner and the original position of the mentioned corner)
2. Draw a similar triangular area on the bottom right corner. For U,W mapping just flip the X and Y.

Comment: 1)Yes, you are right. The image i provided doesn't fit reality for the card, i simply made the picture in flashIDE, for a better understanding.

Comment: Very useful suggestion in num2.But Could you give a sample code to explain that?I'm a little confused...